# Appropirate practices for OCaml interactive development using VScode and the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, ocaml, utop, merlin

I wonder which is the one comfortable way to program in Ocaml (in MAC).

I am currently using the VSCode to detect the syntactic and type errors, but then I use online interpreters to compile (it creates the ml) and to run examples on it; I mean, to instantiate variables, test examples etc. For example, I use the online: https://try.ocamlpro.com/.

I know this is not the best way to do it: for instance, if a package is not integrated (let us say `num`), I cannot do `opam install num` and open it.

So I wonder which is a proper option to have both (1) the cool interface like VSCode and (2) compile + test stuff on the fly.

I think I am close with the next option: I write `ocaml` in the terminal and then a mode is opened:

```
OCaml version 4.10.2
#
#
#
```

...

There, I can write: `#open Num;; #open List;; #let...` but I do not know how to load files on it.

Someone also told me there was something called "utop", but I have looked and it seems advanced for me.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is a good question but the title was misleading as it looked like a typical "opinion-based" question, so I took the liberty to rephrase it to a more direct style. I think that way you will get much better and more useful answers. But, of course, if you think that my edit is too narrow, please feel free to revert/amend it. But keep in mind, that SO favors direct questions and direct answers. I will now work on the answer to your question :)

Comment: My only question is, do you mean 'interactive' or 'iterative' in the title? Both of them suit this question :)

Comment: haha) I just coined a new word, iteractive for interactive/iterative development. But yes, I probably meant interactive (but thought about iterative). Please, correct this to your taste, this will make searching for the question easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mode of development is fully supported by [dune](https://dune.build/) that offers [dune utop](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/toplevel-integration.html) command that will automatically build your project, link it with top-level and start it with all your modules (and external dependencies) available.

Now if you're not yet using dune, you might wonder how to start using it. While the dune documentation is good and thorough, nobody wants to actually spend hours learning Dune, if the only thing that they want is to play with OCaml. So here is the quick tip, to create a ready to run OCaml code, use `dune init`, e.g.,

```
dune init proj play
```

This will create a `play` folder that will have the full OCaml project skeleton fully ready to use. So let's enter it,

```
cd play
```

Now we can easily build and run our project,

```
dune exec play
```

We also have the `play` library in the `lib` folder. It is empty, but you can create any files there, and they will be available in your `bin/main.ml` as well as in `dune utop`, e.g., let's create a simple module,

```
(* file lib/say.ml *)

let hello () = print_endline "Hi!"
```

and then we can use it in our executable,

```
(* file bin/main.ml *)

let () = Play.Say.hello ()
```

and we can play in the OCaml toplevel with our libraries, e.g,

```
$ dune utop
```

and then in the utop shell

```
utop # Play.Say.hello ();;
Hi!
- : unit = ()
```

So what about vscode? So far we played in the console, but `vscode` together with [ocaml-platform](https://github.com/ocamllabs/vscode-ocaml-platform) can do this without leaving the comfort of your editor. You can even select pieces of code and send the toplevel (the default key binding is `Shift-Enter`) that enables interactive and iterative, bottom-up development.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the answer!! The idea looks exactly what I was looking for. However, I am having  one problem: it does not recognise the ```dune utop``` command (has worked fine with the other ones), and sends the message: ```Library "utop" not found```. I have been searching for a solution but cannot find it, any idea? Anyway, thanks a lot again!! (Looks like the closed the question, but I do not agree with the decision)

Comment: I would start with `opam install utop`